# How to import isDate?

Tags: angular, npm

I want to use `isDate()` in one of my methods. Visual Studio Code automatically added `import { isDate } from '@angular/common/src/i18n/format_date'` into my Component. But I get an error when compiling: `ERROR in . . . : error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/John/my-project/node_modules/@angular/common/common"' has no exported member isDate'`

Why is the compiler looking at `/node_modules/@angular/common/common` when the file is in `'@angular/common/src/i18n/format_date'`, and how do I make it look in the right place?

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Member } from '../member';
import { isDate } from '@angular/common/src/i18n/format_date';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-enroll-form',
  templateUrl: './enroll-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./enroll-form.component.css']
})
export class EnrollFormComponent {
  @Input() member: Member = new Member("");

  constructor() {

  }

   memberKeys = Object.keys(this.member);

  primType(s: string) {
    if (typeof(s)==='string' || typeof(s)==='number' || isDate(s)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Isdate method containing module not imported properly

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. How to import properly?

Comment: isDate.isDate(value) try this

Comment: The IDE (Visual Studio Code) rejected that.

Comment: Hm. Your error seems to indicate some problem during the npm install. It's basically saying that one of your libs is broken (in this case, angular itself).

Can you delete node_modules and do npm install again? If that's the problem, it should fix it.

Comment: BTW, you're not meant to directly import the `isDate` method from the file declaring the method. Instead, import from the main module (i.e. `@angular/common`)

Answer (score 1):

Date isn't really a data type in javascript. But to know if something's a Date object it can be tested with instanceof against Date.

try to create your own function and call it in primType function

```
// Returns if value is a date object
isDate (value) {
   return value instanceof Date;
}
```

and even remove the below line from the code and try it out it works..

```
import { isDate } from '@angular/common/src/i18n/format_date';
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Anusha_Mamidala. That worked to clear up the errors, but before I mark that as answer, my problem is that in TypeScript I declared as type `Date` the variable I'm passing as `value` to isDate, but the variable hasn't been initialized to an actual date yet, so isDate will return `false`.  What I really want (which may merit another question altogether) is to find out how the variable has been declared, not what value it's currently holding. Is there a way to find out how a variable has been declared in TypeScript? Tks!

Comment: do you mean to say that you wanted to check whether the value is undefined or null or it has some value

Comment: No. I don't care about the value at all. I just want to see what type the variable was declared as. I'm beginning to worry it's not possible, because at runtime, Javascript doesn't have any reference to how a TypeScript variable was declared. Unless I'm wrong on that, I think I'll have to use a workaround, like using a special naming convention for `Date` type variables . . .

Comment: If you can declare the variable like `const d: Date = new Date();` then it is possible. If it is not possible can I know the use case of it clearly or can you post your sample code in [stackblitz](http://www.stackblitz.com) so that I can think of the use cases and post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly, my IDE (Visual Studio Code) gave me an option for isDate in 'util' (I don't believe that option was available to me previously). When I `import { isDate } from 'util';` everything works fine now.